# Except the name of table what property can use to differentiate these tables

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I have a database which contains many tables and these tables can be added or removedd any time.So I give each of them a different name like Table1,Table2,...
but it's uncomfortable to use these table because sometime I forget what infomation was stored in Table1
So I want something to differentiate these all tables, some property that I can be specified when I create a table and I can use to access a specific table when I need to fetch informations from that table

Comment: Create a table TableNotes with two columns: TableName, Note.  In it put information about that table if you need to fetch it...?

Answer (score 0):

As one comment says, you could create a table for notes on the other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_name VARCHAR(64),
    note VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

By the way, MySQL (but not SQLite) allows comments on the table itself:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    val INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COMMENT = 'Table of stuff';

-- Show the comment
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME='table1';

-- Just show names and comments
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`, `TABLE_COMMENT`
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();
```

Comment: Thank you, I've never knew this before

Comment: @CL, you're right. I think I misread this as a MySQL question. I updated the answer to note that comments on tables do not work in SQLite.